# \qed for MathJax here on stackexchange

Tags: discussion, mathjax

How to get MathJax render the \qed-command?
Is there a way to use it?
Maybe aligning the $\Box$ \Box under the current line?

Answer (score 27):

This can be obtained nicely using `$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$`:

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: Use `\tag*` to eliminate the brackets.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I looked but I didn't find it. I have `MathJax is not full LaTeX` drilled pretty deep and I didn't think to try this sort of intuition.

Comment: $$\tag*{\(\blacksquare\)}$$ works very well for me

`$$\tag*{\(\blacksquare\)}$$`

Answer (score 17):

The command that gives the tombstone is part of amsthm (or other theorem environment packages). The positioning of the tombstone is actually quite complicated, and I do not believe it is currently implemented in MathJax, nor do I think it will be in the near future.

Let me emphasize: **MathJax is not, and was never intended to be** a full featured dynamic LaTeX parser. It is a platform for displaying mathematics coded using TeX or MathML notation in an aesthetic way.

If you **must** have an Halmos symbol, you will have to kludge it yourself by inserting sufficiently much spacing (possibly with `&nbsp;`s or `\qquads` inside dollar signs) and place $\Box$  (`\Box`) or $\blacksquare$ (`\blacksquare`) yourself.

But let me ask: what's wrong with just typing the three letters "q.e.d."?