# How do you tag without brackets? In particular, how do you tag boxes?

Tags: support, feature-request, mathjax

How would you tag boxes without brackets after completing a proof? For example, I needed to prove that $$\forall m, n \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}, \ n^{2m + 1} \equiv -1 \pmod {n + 1}$$ I proved this by showing that $$n^{2m + 1} + 1 = n^{2m + 1} - (-1) = n^{2m + 1} - (-1)^{2m + 1}$$ And since $$a^k - b^k = (a - b)\sum_{i = 1}^k a^{k - i}b^{i - 1}$$ then this meant $$n + 1 \mid n^{2m + 1} + 1$$ or $$n^{2m + 1} \equiv -1 \pmod {n + 1}$$ In the event that I want to draft up a proof using LATEX, how would I tag a box $\Box$ to show that I have demonstrated the proof without it having brackets like $(\Box)$? Namely, if I had a *Statement $A$* then I don’t want it looking like $$\text{Statement $A$}\tag{$\Box$}$$ and if I use *\quad* and/or *\qquad* then it looks like $$\text{Statement $A$}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \ \ \ \ \Box$$ Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: I agree with what mixedmath says in their answer that this is not a reasonable thing to do in order to *mark the end of a proof.* I read your question simply as a TeX-nical (or MathJax-nical) question: "How do I mark equation with $\Box$ rather than $(\Box)$ on the right?"

Probably the intended question is related to possibilities how to mark end of proof (in a way similar to `\qed` in LaTeX), which is question related to style of writing and MathJax. (And which means that I have misunderstood your question.) Probably you might have a look at past discussion here: [\qed for MathJax here on stackexchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3582).

---

If you do not net MathJax markup in the tag you can do this simply using \tag*. Compare the following two equations:
`$$a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag{1}$$`
$$a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag{1}$$
and 
`$$a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag*{1}$$`
$$a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag*{1}$$

It is slightly complicated if you want some mathematical formula as a part of the tag, see also here: [I can't put a Greek letter into `\tag{…}`](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12455)

You can do this
`$$a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag{$\Box$}$$`
$$a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag{$\Box$}$$
and also this
`$$a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag*{$\Box$}$$`
$$a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag*{$\Box$}.$$

Answer (score 5):

I would typically expect you to include a box inline, such as this. $\square$

An indication that you are trying to do something in a way that isn't how it is designed is that you are trying to use `tag` to produce something other than a tag or label.

If you really want to shove a square to the far right, I only know how to do this (with mathjax) in a `multline` environment, as below.

$$\begin{multline}
\shoveright
\square
\end{multline}$$

But I would suggest that you never do this.

Comment: Interestingly, using `\tag*` is one of the suggested solutions in [the previous discussion about this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/qed-for-mathjax-here-on-stackexchange/13338#13338). I will leave to others to judge whether this is good style or not. (Personally I consider the advice from your answer very reasonable.)

Answer (score 1):

I mostly separate sections on this site with

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

which usually comes out matching the width of my answer window. My idea is that people can't read this site as carefully as a book they are holding in their hands, something that crosses the window gives a more reliable notice that something different is starting. if you want to say QED  before that, fine.

Comment: I will add that it is also possible to use simply `<hr>` or `---`. (In which case you do not have to worry about the length, the SE software does that for you.) For other possibilities, see the section on [horizontal rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#horizontal-rules) in [editing help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: It might match the width of your answer window, but other people might be viewing in a phone browser or with different fonts installed on their computers. `---` is much more consistent.